# Error adding new models to database Django

Tags: python, django, database

## models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## Genres.py

```
from MyVideoGames.models import Genre
from ClientIGDB import ClientIGDB

genres = ClientIGDB.api_call("genres", ["name"], 50)

for genre in genres:
    g = Genre.objects.create(name=genre["name"])
    g.save()
```

When I'm trying to add some models to sqlite db i'm not able to do this import:
`from myproj.models import Genre`. I don't know why...
When I do it this error is shown:

`% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`
If someone can help me I'll be really gratefull

Comment: When exactly is that error happening? When you run ``makemigrations``?

Comment: No, it happens when I run genre.py in order to update te db using data from an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you run a script that uses python models you need to tell python that django exists first. Try this at the beginning of your script:

```
import os
import sys
import django 

sys.path.append("/path/to/your/project")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "yourProjectName.settings"
django.setup()
```

It's like a mini settings.py. You are not running something 'inside' django, so you need to start things up first. I wonder if anybody else could refine this to a solution that we don't need to hard code this every time we write a new script.